# How to print gerber files? (mac)

Tags: pcb, gerber

I'm currently using circuits.io to create a very simple circuit. However, before ordering the board, I would like to print it in order to see if it's the right size and/or the elements fit in my own designed footprints.

Since circuit.io only lets you download gerber files, is there a simple way to print those gerber files? Maybe if someone can point me to the spec for the gerber files I could craft a simple script to convert the file to something that I could actually print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gerbv - A Free/Open Source Gerber Viewer, part of [gplEDA](http://gerbv.gpleda.org/index.html), does what you want. Specifically it is at http://gerbv.geda-project.org/.

Comment: thanks, I'll try that... as soon as I can compile it :S the macports version is not compiling right now, and I haven't found a binary version

Comment: ok, I completely wiped out macports and installed fink... that did the trick! thanks :)

Comment: just an update: I removed fink and I'm now with [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/), that seems more updated and it worked right out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

[gerbv](http://gerbv.gpleda.org/index.html) is available for OS X.  It can print to PDF or PostScript.

Answer (score 2):

With [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed, type in your terminal:

`brew install gerbv`

let it install then type:

`gerbv`

and it will open